# Sliding Menu Android: Source not found

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm newbie in Android programming.
I've read many tutorial in the Internet about Sliding Menu on https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.
1. Import library in my project.
2. Create an .xml in layout folder.
3. Modify MainActivity like this:

```
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends SlidingActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.copyactivity_main);
    getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

It have no error. But when I debug it in emulator. It stopped and have the error: Source not found.
I don't know what it is.
Any help, thanks.

Comment: must sure that this library project is in your Work space....

Comment: Library is in my Work space too.